# Could someone give me the explanation for this scenario?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

I fixed inclined wedge. I throw a ball from height say h meters above its point of impact of the inclined plane. And lets say the inclined plane is smooth (no friction) but has a coefficient of restitution say, e.

Now when the ball rebounds of the incline, on what basis can we say that the horizonal velocity of components along the incline of the ball before and after rebound will be the same?

When I checked up on the web all that I got was since no frictional force or external force acts along the direction of incline, the horizontal velocity components along the incline of the ball (before and after rebound) will be the same. But this isn't very convincing explanation to me.

Is there any mathematical proof for this. Please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of conservation of momentum axiom? Axioms are distillates of observations and measurements and can only be proven or disproved by data. Do you know that momentum is defined as p=mv in each velocity direction?

Comment: Why is it not convincing? If there are no forces along the horizontal, the component of velocity in that direction will not change.

Comment: It's horizontal relative to the plane. That part doesn't change. Horizontal relative to the ground does change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested in the change in the ball's momentum during the collision. The collision takes place in a very short time interval: the average force required to affect a change in momentum so significant as to make the ball bounce back in such a short time is enormous, much greater than the ball's weight, so the weight can be safely neglected during the collision. Since there is no friction, the force on the ball during the collision is in the normal direction, i.e. $\vec F = F \hat n$, where $\hat n$ is the unit normal vector pointing away from the inclined plane.

Newton's second law says
$$\frac{d\vec p}{dt}=\vec F=F\hat n.$$

Integrating from just before the collision to just after:
$$\int\limits_{t_\text{before}}^{t_\text{after}}\frac{d\vec p}{dt}dt=\int\limits_{t_\text{before}}^{t_\text{after}}F(t)\hat ndt.$$
$$\vec p_\text{after}-\vec p_\text{before}=\hat n\int\limits_{t_\text{before}}^{t_\text{after}}F(t)dt.$$
$$\vec v_\text{after}-\vec v_\text{before}=\frac{\hat n}{m}\int\limits_{t_\text{before}}^{t_\text{after}}F(t)dt.$$
This shows that the change in velocity during the collision is also in the normal direction.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct for a non-zero coefficient of restitution.

Comment: @SeñorO I have made no assumption about the coefficient of restitution, other than that the force on the ball is in the normal direction, which is what I assume "no friction" means in this context.